# Xml parsing value node with java

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing

I am parsing XML and I have a question, here is my code:

```
                XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
            String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
            Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element


            NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_SONG);


            // looping through all song nodes <song>
            for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value





                map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ONE));
                map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TWOO));
                map.put(KEY_CARATULA, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THREE));
                map.put(KEY_DURACION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_FOUR));



               ****====> if (variable.equalsIgnoreCase(e.get){
                songsList.add(map);
                }
```

How can I compare variable with the value of KEY_ONE for example? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options (assuming `variable` is a `String`).

You could just grab it from the parser once, e.g.:

```
String keyOne = parser.getValue(e, KEY_ONE);

map.put(KEY_ID, keyOne);
map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TWOO));
map.put(KEY_CARATULA, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THREE));
map.put(KEY_DURACION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_FOUR));

...

if (variable.equalsIgnoreCase(keyOne)) {
   ...
}
```

Or you could just get it from the parser twice, e.g.:

```
if (variable.equalsIgnoreCase(parser.getValue(e, KEY_ONE)) {
   ...
}
```

Or you could pull it back out of your map, e.g.:

```
if (variable.equalsIgnoreCase(map.get(KEY_ID)) {
   ...
}
```

The first option (storing it in `keyOne`) is the approach I'd personally take, it seems the most natural, and it's kind of second-nature to me to avoid extra computation (e.g. parser / map look-ups) even if it doesn't noticeably affect actual performance. But any of these should work just fine.

Comment: Thank you, perhaps something I´m doing wrong because I can´t get the value like this

Comment: @Igor Can you edit your answer to show your actual code along with any specific errors you are receiving?